# document.setAttribute

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

Can this be used to change CSS? Cant see much on w3 about it. Anyone know anything about it.

If this forum/site isnt the place for asking browser standard questions, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

--Mark

Comment: What do you mean by change CSS?

Comment: Mark -- you're in the right place. Welcome :-)

Comment: sorry. meant to say elements style.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use setAttribute to change the CSS of a single DOM element, like so:

```
document.getElementById("something").setAttribute("style", "color: red;");
```

However, I believe it's bad practice.  You can modify the stylesheet as Marius pointed out by doing:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
```

or by manually editing the style attributes of HTML elements, like:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
```

I would recommend looking into [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), as it has powerful and easy to use tools for modifying the CSS of DOM elements.  It's as simple as:

```
$("#someID").css({"color": "red", "width": "100px"});
```

Comment: thanks. That is what i was thinking. Hasnt document.stylesheets been removed from the w3 standards?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean. If you want to set a CSS value, for example background color, then you have to set that on some element, for example the body:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
```

If you want to change the CSS stylesheet, then you can use the styleSheets object:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
```

setAttribute is used to set the attribute of some html element, for example the href in an anchor element:

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.goolge.com">google</a>



document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```