# If I want box2 to change color to red on mouseon, would using setAttribute be correct like this?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Events!</title>

<!-- Loading my CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="box-container">
    <div class="box" id="box1">I'm a box</div>
    <div class="box" id="box2">I'm a box</div>
    <div class="box" id="box3">I'm a box</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="tricky-box">Tricky box</div>

<button id="secret-button">Super Secret</button>

<input id="secret-input"></input>

<!-- Ignore this stuff till later -->
<br>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<br>

<div class="d1">1
    <div class="d2">2
        <div class="d3">3</div>
    </div>
</div>




<!-- Loading my JS -->
<script src="js/myapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So I want box2 to change color to red on mouseon and I was wondering this would be correct:

```
 window.onload = function() {

 box2.onmouseover = function(event){
box2.setAttribute = ("style", "background-color: red;"); 
 }
```

The color did not change..so obviously, I'm doing something wrong. Anyone know the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Please add a link to a fiddle example to support easy comprehension and trouble-shooting.

Answer (score 6):

`setAttribute` is a method, not an object property.

You can do either the DOM style object:

```
box2.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

or the proper `setAttribute` method:

```
box2.setAttribute("style","background-color:red");
```

See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed you script. Check the snippet-

```js
box2.onmouseover = function(event){
  box2.style.backgroundColor  = "red"; 
 }
```

```html
<div id="box-container">
    <div class="box" id="box1">I'm a box</div>
    <div class="box" id="box2">I'm a box</div>
    <div class="box" id="box3">I'm a box</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="tricky-box">Tricky box</div>

<button id="secret-button">Super Secret</button>

<input id="secret-input"></input>

<!-- Ignore this stuff till later -->
<br>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<br>

<div class="d1">1
    <div class="d2">2
        <div class="d3">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making only one mistake. Just remove equal sign and your code will work.

Your Code

```
 window.onload = function() {

 box2.onmouseover = function(event){
box2.setAttribute = ("style", "background-color: red;"); 
 }
```

Correct Code

```
 window.onload = function() {

 box2.onmouseover = function(event){
box2.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;"); 
 }
```

For more information please see following link.

[document.setAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225362/document-setattribute)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using getElementById() and then set class name that refers to a css class, like in this working example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Events!</title>
  <style>
  .red {
    background-color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
     window.onload = function() {
        box2.onmouseover = function(event){
          alert("Hello");
          var box = document.getElementById("box2");
          box.className = box.className + " red";
        }
      }
  </script>

  </head>
<body>
<div id="box-container">
    <div class="box" id="box1">I'm a box</div>
    <div class="box" id="box2">I'm a box</div>
    <div class="box" id="box3">I'm a box</div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="tricky-box">Tricky box</div>

<button id="secret-button">Super Secret</button>

<input id="secret-input"></input>

<!-- Ignore this stuff till later -->
<br>
<hr>
<hr>
<hr>
<br>

<div class="d1">1
    <div class="d2">2
        <div class="d3">3</div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of pure curiosity: Why wouldn't you do this just with CSS?

```
#box2:hover {
    background: red;
}
```